# How can I combine attribute selectors for elements that match one or the other?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I combine selectors?
I want to hide the arrows in a number and a date field

```
<input type=number>
<input type=date>
```

I found the following code which works fine for a single field:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

But now I want to add type=date in the some code but cannot seem to combine them and looked everywhere how to do it but cannot find how. I suspect it to be something really simple like below but that does not work.

```
input[type=number][type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number][type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

I know there are workarounds like using ID's but since I'm learning CSS I want to know how to combine [type=date] and [type=number] in a single string of code. Anybody any idea's?

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<input type=number>
<input type=date>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted solution will target only inputs that have both type=number and type=date. So that won't work.
You need type=number **OR** type=date, and unfortunately the following is the only way to do that.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Note, by the way, that `-webkit-inner-spin-button` is a webkit-proprietary pseudo-element, so it won't work in other browsers. Specifically, the `-moz-appearance` line is completely superfluous!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css like this:

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<input type=number>
<input type=date>
```